# A question about convergence and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $f_{m,n}$ is continuous alomst everywhere, and $f_{m,n}$ converges to $g_{m}$ alomst everywhere as $n \to \infty$, $g_{m}$ converges uniformly to $g$ almost everywhere as $m \to \infty$. Can we find $\{h_{k}\}_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ such that $h_{k}$ is continuous almost everywhere and $h_{k}$ converges to $g$ almost everywhere as $k \to \infty$?

I want to prove that $g_{m}$ is continuous almost everywhere, but I failed. I also tried to choose $h_{k}=f_{k,k}$, but it didn't work, either.

Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think this is true, though I don't have a counter-example off-hand, so I could be wrong. It is certainly not true that the $g_m$ have to be continuous almost everywhere, since you did not assume uniform convergence of the $f_{m,n}$. And since the $g_m$ do not have to be continuous almost everywhere, the fact that they converge uniformly is not going to guarantee continuity of $g$.

Comment: I find a proof and it doesn't use the uniform convergence, could you please help me to check it?

Answer (score 0):

I find a proof and it doesn't use the uniform convergence.
We have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{m,n}(x)=g_{m}(x), ~a.e.
$$

$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}g_{m}(x)=g(x), ~a.e.
$$

$\forall k \geqslant 1$, $g_{m}$ converges to $g$ almost everywhere on $[-k,k]$, by Egoroff's Theorem we know there exists $E_{k}$ such that $\mu(E_{k}) < 2^{-k}$ and $g_{m}$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $[-k,k] \setminus E_{k}$, so there exists $m_{k}$ such that

$$
|g_{m_{k}}(x)-g(x)| < 2^{-k}, ~\forall x \in [-k,k] \setminus E_{k}
$$

In the same way, $f_{m_{k},n}$ converge to $g_{m_{k}}$ almost everywhere on $[-k,k] \setminus E_{k}$, by Egoroff's Theorem there exists $n_{k}$ and $F_{k}$ such that

$$
\mu(F_{k}) < 2^{-k},~ |f_{m_{k},n_{k}}(x)-g_{m_{k}}(x)| < 2^{-k}, ~\forall x \in [-k,k] \setminus (E_{k} \cup F_{k})
$$

Let $G_{k}=\cup_{l \geqslant k}(E_{l} \cup F_{l})$, then $\mu(G_{k}) < 2^{2-k}$, $G_{k}$ is decreasing,

$$
|f_{m_{k},n_{k}}(x)-g(x)| < 2^{1-k}, ~\forall x \in [-k,k] \setminus G_{k}
$$

so $f_{m_{k},n_{k}}$ converges to $g$ almost everywhere.